# python eval inside a class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to write a lot of Python code which will look like the following:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def handle_request(self, request):
        attr1 = self.__get_attr1(request)
        self.__validate_attr1(attr1)

        attr2 = self.__get_attr2(request)
        self.__validate_attr2(attr2)

        attr3 = self.__get_attr3(request)
        self.__validate_attr1(attr3)
        ...
        ...
        ...
        attrn = self.__get_attrn(request)
        self.__validate_attrn(attr1)
```

To make my life easier I thought I could do the following:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def handle_request(self, request):
        attr_list = ('attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', ..., 'attrn');
        for a in attr_list:
            locals()[a] = eval('self.__get_{}(request)'.format(a))
            eval('self.__validate_{}'.format(a)
```

However when I run this code I'm getting a following error:

```
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '__get_attr1'
```

Clearly I'm missing something big but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: You  clearly haven't defined the value of `__get_attr1` before using it.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac assume __get_attr methods are defined.

Comment: I may, but too bad your program couldn't do the same. Could you access `__get_attr1` by any other means outside `eval`?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac What do you mean by other means?

Comment: Like simply printing it before using eval, `print(self.__get_attr1)`

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac If the question is, can I access it using `self.__get_attr1(request)`, the answer is yes. I have a lot of those attributes to extract and validate. Would be nice if I could do it in a few lines of code.

Comment: can't you create one universal function to get attr - `__get('attr1', request)` ? you could use dictionary to assign validator to `attr`, even with different name and more then one - `{'attr1': (self.__validate_email, self.__validate_no_empty)}`

Comment: you don't need `eval()` - use `getattr()`

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you didn't ask, instead of using `eval`, you might try something like

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr_list = [self.__get_attr1, ..., self.__get_attrn]
        self.validate_list = [self.__validate_attr1, ..., self.__validate_attrn]
    ...
    def handle_request(self, request):
        attrs = [get(request) for get in self.attr_list]
        for validate in self.validate_list:
            validate(request)
```

Comment: Or just `getattr(self, attribute_name)`.